# Logarithm question equation

Tags: logarithms

I'm stuck on an equation :

$$(\log_8 x)^2+2\log_8 x+1=0$$

I've played with it without any success. Any indications would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I did an error ! (log8 (x))2+2log8 x+1=0 Here's the real one !

Comment: By $(\log8(x))$, do you mean $\log(8x)$ or $((\log8)x)$, or something else?  Either of those last two is unambiguous, but the notation you used is ambiguous.

Comment: 8 is the base of the logarithm.

Comment: OK, I've edited the article accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You've got $u^2+2u+1=0$, where $u=\log_8x$.

Factoring, you get $(u+1)^2=0$, which entails that $u=-1$.

If $\log_8x=-1$ then $8^{-1}=x$, i.e. $x=\dfrac18$.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh...... It makes sense ! I'm angry with myself for not having thought of it :( Thank you very much !